# How to Convert my Joomla site to WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, joomla

I have a potential client who wants to take an existing Joomla site and translate it into Wordpress.How can i ?

Comment: Tried googling a bit for an importer?

Comment: I ended up doing it al by hand. There is also a importer http://wordpress.org/plugins/fg-joomla-to-wordpress/ don't know what the quality is today.

Comment: yes,i read .google is saying there is plugins for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's all documented. Read http://codex.wordpress.org/Importing_Content and http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development if you want to convert a Joomla theme to a Wordpress theme.

Answer (score -1):

You may do a standard migration however if you have any customer database tables with valuable data you need to make sure you don't forget about it. Such tables may include e-commerce related with customer data.

If that is the case you could use plugins like CSV 2 POST, Easy CSV Importer or Wordpress CSV Importer. You would need to export your existing database as CSV file though. These Wordpress plugins will allow you to import any CSV file with any number of columns into Wordpress to create posts, their authors and import e-commerce data to Wordpress shopping cart plugins.

Exporting the data is best done using a tool that puts all tables into one CSV file however if you cannot do that. CSV 2 POST works with multiple CSV files and merges the files to create your posts.

This is all very advanced though and required if you have more than the average installation of Joomla.